# Balls on boundary of a set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a subset in a metric space $(X,d)$ with non-empty interior. Let $x$ be a point in the boundary of $A$. Does $B_{\delta}(x)$ intersect the interior of $A$ for all $\delta$?

This is a step I need when doing another problem. Geometrically it feels right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not necessarily. Take the subset $[0, 1] \cup \{ 2\}$ of $\Bbb{R}$. The set has non-empty interior $(0, 1)$, and is closed, so the boundary is
$$([0, 1] \cup \{2\}) \setminus (0, 1) = \{0, 1, 2\}.$$
The ball $B_{\frac{1}{2}}(2)$ fails to intersect $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Ahhh that sucks. Do you mind taking a look at this problem? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102203/proving-continuity-and-discontinuity/3102790?noredirect=1#comment6394772_3102790

Comment: @FluffySkye I had a look and left a comment.

Comment: I'm reading it now. You're my savior!